# how to get a saved value in redis and use it again (django)

Tags: python, django, redis

I'm new to redis.

developing a django project, I wonder how to set a value in redis in one function in my `views.py` and in another function get it and use it again.

can anyone help me with an actual example?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use redis as a cache backend?It's simple.First install **django-redis-cache** then in settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'server:6379',
    },
}


from django.core.cache import cache

>>> cache.set('my_key', 'hello, world!', 30)
>>> cache.get('my_key')
'hello, world!
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to look into Redis server than you have a command for this**

```
➜  ~ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "key1"
127.0.0.1:6379> get "key1"
hello
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

https://redis.io/topics/rediscli

**for in Django code example would be like this**

```
from django.core.cache import cache



def view_cached_books(request):
    if 'product' in cache:
        # get results from cache
        products = cache.get('product')
        return Response(products, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    else:
        products = Product.objects.all()
        results = [product.to_json() for product in products]
        # store data in cache
        cache.set(product, results, timeout=CACHE_TTL)
        return Response(results, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**for Django shell**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520967/6839331